# How to save an array in one cell?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

How do I store a complete array in database in symfony. My content of the array is a shopping cart:

```
article_id / article  / amount / price
```

example:

```
1 / knife / 4 / 4$
2 / for / 6 / 2$
```

How can I store the complete array in one cell?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Might want to check out `serialize` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the object column type of doctrine. This will `serialize()` and `deserialize()` your contents.

See: http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_0/en/defining-models:columns:data-types#object

Answer (score 1):

You could [`serialize()`](http://php.net/serialize) the array before storing it in the database and use [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/unserialize) after retrieving it.

Answer (score 1):

Serialize() & unserialize() reference

http://www.tanzilo.com/2008/12/31/php-serialization-unserialization-explanation-code-example/